# $M/\Bbb R$ is not Hausdorf and becomes a manifold upon removing four well-chosen points, $M = \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(0; 0)\}$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Given smooth action of $\Bbb R$ on $M = \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(0; 0)\}$ :
$g \cdot (m_1, m_2) = (e^tm_1, e^{-t}m_2)$

The $\Bbb R$-action stabilizes the subset $S = [0,+\infty) \times  (0,+\infty)$. Prove that

0. The action is free.
1. $S/\Bbb R$, with the quotient topology, is homeomorphic to $[0,+\infty)$ (with the Euclidean topology).
2. The quotient topology on $M/\Bbb R$ is not Hausdorff.
3. **Prove that $M/\Bbb R$ becomes a manifold upon removing four well-chosen points**

I already solved the first 2 points, which might be useful for the other two. I am having trouble with those. How can I show that? in the last point  first I have to  make it into a Hausdorff space I guess.

Edit:

About the orbits, to find them I did this:

Let say I want to find the orbit (class) of $(a,b )$ \in $M$
So I fix $(a,b)$,  I want to find all the $(x,y)$ such that $(x,y) \sim (a,b)$ which means that there must exist some $g \in G=\Bbb R$ such that $g\cdot(x,y)= (a,b)$  that is  $(x e^t, y e^-t)=(a,b)$ so  I get two equations:  $xe^t=a$ and $y e^{-t }=b$
Analyzing by cases I find these cases:

$a=0$, $b \neq 0, b > 0:   (x,y)= (0,be^t)$ that is all the point of the form $(0 , x)$ with $x > 0$
In the same way

$a=0, b \neq 0,  b <0:$    the class is $(0,x)$ with $x < 0$

$b=0, a \neq 0,  a >0:$    the class is $(x,0)$ with $x > 0$

$b=0, a \neq 0,  a <0: $   the class is $(x,0)$ with $x < 0$

And for the case $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$  I have  from $xe^t=a$ and $y e^{-t }=b$ that   $xy=ab$, so those are hyperbolas. for every value of the non-zero constant $ab$
Am I right that these are all  the orbits?

Then what would the neighborhoods of (0,1) will look like? I think like this: the +y semiaxis plus a continuous of hyperbolas next to it, that I think at the end you get the whole region of the I quadrant under a certain hyperbola withouth including the origin and the semiaxis x+.

Is all of this correct? What should I do next?

[image]

Comment: Well, what four points do you think are problematic? If you solved 2 then you probably know.

Comment: Actually it's only necessary to remove two points. By the way, here "points" means "points of $M/\mathbb R$", i.e., "$\mathbb R$-orbits in $M$".

Comment: @SeanEberhard Actually i didn't I updated my question, the first point was actually proving that the action was free, the second the homeomorphism. So I am having trouble with that too. Could you please guide me through them? Regarding your second comment do you mean the text is probably refering to points of M that after quotienting out become two points ?

Comment: Let $[p]$ denote the image of $p$ in $M / \mathbb R$. What does a neighbourhood of $[(0,1)]$ look like? What does a neighbourhood of $[(1,0)]$ look like? That should get you thinking along the right lines. It may also be helpful to think about the map $f : M \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x, y) = xy$, which is not quite the quotient map but closely related to it.

Comment: @SeanEberhard what are the elements of for isntance, the class [(0,1)] ? The fact that the action is free means that all orbits are trivial i.e $ G_m=\{g \in \Bbb R: g.m=m\}=\{0\}$. Does this help for anything? The quotient is the set of orbits, that is mean that there is only one orbit?

Comment: The stabilizer is trivial, not the orbit.

Comment: @SeanEberhard See my edit, could you tell me if it is correct and what to do next? Now the point that are problematic are those first 4 clases I think. but how does removing them fixes Hausdorffness?

Comment: That is much better. One correction: the hyperbola $xy=c$ for any fixed nonzero value of $c$ is not one orbit but two, depending on the sign of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: As for what the space looks like when those points are removed, you should be able to use your answer to 1.

Comment: @SeanEberhard So I remove the classes [(0,1)], [(0,-1)] ,[(1,0)], [(-1,0)]  and I am left with four parallel semi-straight line , how can Argue that that is a manifold? I mean every straight line is a manifolds by itself, but in $\Bbb R^2 $ these are not open sets

Comment: If you can prove the space is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of four copies of $(0,\infty)$ with the standard topology (which is itself homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$), then you are done, because that is a manifold. It doesn't matter that it's not an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$.